# SwiftyJSON- Iterate through objects with ID which are not an array

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am making a request to an API that sometimes returns an array of simple JSON objects, which I am parsing with a simple "for i in count" loop, where I use SwiftyJSON to append json[i]["city"]. For example:

```
[{"city":"Lakefront","code":"NEW","country":"United States","municipality":"New Orleans","isChild":false,"hasChild":false},
{"city":"Auckland - Auckland International Airport","code":"AKL","country":"New Zealand","municipality":"Auckland","isChild":false,"hasChild":false},
{"city":"Blenheim","code":"BHE","country":"New Zealand","municipality":"Blenheim","isChild":false,"hasChild":false}]
```

However, in certain cases, the API will return an object with multiple pairs of keys and object values, which I am having trouble parsing with SwiftyJSON. For example:

```
{"2":{"city":"New York","code":"NYC","country":"United States","municipality":"New York","isChild":false,"hasChild":true},
"32":{"city":"John F. Kennedy -  NY","code":"JFK","country":"United States","municipality":"New York","isChild":true,"hasChild":false},
"414":{"city":"LaGuardia -  NY","code":"LGA","country":"United States","municipality":"New York","isChild":true,"hasChild":false}}
```

In this second case, is there a way to loop through the first object with SwiftyJSON, and get the object value noting that I will not know the ID (2, 32, 414) in advance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your first case you have an array of dictionaries. In the second case you have a dictionary of dictionaries. I haven't used SwiftyJSON in long enough that I don't remember how it works, but that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: This is the basis of the answer. But I can't find a way to cast a JSON object into a [String:Any] dictionary.

Comment: Ignoring SwiftyJSON, you just say `guard let dict = aJSONObject as [String:Any] else {return}`